# Arrange the heading in single line

Tags: moderncv

Here is my modern cv latex code

```
\cvline{Nov 2012-Jan 2013}{\Large Heading} \hfill {\em Client Name}
```

I'm trying to build a resume and want the above Data in a single line but the last portion `Client Name` drop down to the next line.

How to get this in one horizontal line

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you simply messed up your braces:

```
\cvline{Nov 2012-Jan 2013}{{\Large Heading} \hfill {\em Client Name}}
```

gives everything on one line.

When you don't include the extra / missing set of braces, there is no space left on the line with `\cvline` (due to how it is constructed internally), and the following `\hfill` and text block get pushed on a new line.